# How to create excel column allowes only unique strings using java apache poi api

Tags: java, apache-poi

i want to create excel using **Java Apache POI API** contain one column with name **EMPLOYEENAME** it allows  only unique names.

How can do it using **Java Apache POI API** ?

[image]

Comment: step one: read the api-documentation. step two: think. about what you read step three: read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting your next question.

Comment: How would you do this in Excel itself? Start with that, then check how to setup the sames rules / constraints / etc in POI

Answer (score 1):

why not keep track of all names in a list?
Something like:

```
List<String> listUniqueEmployeeNames = new ArrayList<String>();

if(!listUniqueEmployeeNames.contains(employeename)) {
    listUniqueEmployeeNames.add(employeename);
//do the rest of inserting cells for this employee here
}
```

Comment: i want to perform excel validation in sheet itself not serverside validation

Comment: I may be wrong but I am very sure that you will have to write some code, vb, java or even excel functions to determine if you have duplicate entries and than react to it, e.g. popup message, automatic deletion or what ever you want